# What are all the mongoose events and where are they documented?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

There are various events I can handle with mongoose, e.g.

```
mongoose.connection.on("connecting", () => this.onConnecting());
```

Some of those I've encountered:

- connecting
- error
- connected
- open
- reconnected
- disconnected

I can't find where these are documented. I thought that maybe they weren't part of mogoose, but rather of mongodb itself, but I couldn't find them on the mongo site either.

Where can I find these events (and others) documented?

Comment: Maybe now they have documented them here https://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html#connection-events

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can find it on github in the source code. https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/master/lib/connection.js

There are many more events listed than the given answer, here they are:

- @event `connecting`: Emitted when `connection.openUri()` is executed on this connection.
- @event `connected`: Emitted when this connection successfully connects to the db. May be emitted *multiple* times in `reconnected` scenarios.
- @event `open`: Emitted after we `connected` and `onOpen` is executed on all of this connections models.
- @event `disconnecting`: Emitted when `connection.close()` was executed.
- @event `disconnected`: Emitted after getting disconnected from the db.
- @event `close`: Emitted after we `disconnected` and `onClose` executed on all of this connections models.
- @event `reconnected`: Emitted after we `connected` and subsequently `disconnected`, followed by successfully another successfull connection.
- @event `error`: Emitted when an error occurs on this connection.
- @event `fullsetup`: Emitted in a replica-set scenario, when primary and at least one seconaries specified in the connection string are connected.
- @event `all`: Emitted in a replica-set scenario, when all nodes specified in the connection string are connected.

Comment: This isn't really documentation, but I have a feeling this is the best we can get in the Node world. Thanks for this.

Comment: Yeah sorry about that. Mongoose documentation is really bad... From my experience, they often don't document mildly complex things -_-

Comment: when is onOpen called?

Comment: Note that there are also model events, like "index".

Answer (score 1):

By looking into the source code if found where the events are centralized :

https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/2176150b3d463747ba66b76e37504ee8ffc3f738/lib/connectionstate.js

here is a copy-pasta :

```
const disconnected = 'disconnected';
const connected = 'connected';
const connecting = 'connecting';
const disconnecting = 'disconnecting';
const uninitialized = 'uninitialized';
```

UPDATE :

Check @ajbieber 's answer for the full list.

Comment: That isn't documentation, and can change at any time. I appreciate the effort though, because now I know there is also "uninitialized". The problem is all blogs and SO posts are copy-pasta but strangely enough there is no docs anywhere... (well, docs that I've managed to find)

Comment: I found this : https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#connection_Connection-readyState but indeed it doesn't show everything, might be worth it to file an issue asking if it's possible to add this to the doc and keep it in sync with the connectionstate.js file perhaps ?