# Difference between mongoose's open/connected and close/disconnected events

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, node-mongodb-native

Mongoose's documentation isn't that helpful in some areas. I need to know the difference between these sets of events:

`"open"` vs `"connected"`

and

`"close"` vs `"disconnected"`

[Buried](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/master/lib/connection.js)  in the source there is this:

- connected: Emitted when this connection successfully connects to the db. May be emitted multiple times in reconnected scenarios.
- open: Emitted after we connected and onOpen is executed on all of this connections models.
- disconnected: Emitted after getting disconnected from the db.
- close: Emitted after we disconnected and onClose executed on all of this connections models.

That shows a precedence - first "connected" then "open", and first "disconnected" then "closed". However that doesn't explain the difference between them.

For example, the docs say that [close](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#connection_Connection-close) "Closes the connection". How is this different to disconnecting? Same for open/connect.

---

UPDATE
This is NOT a dupe of that question (which I wrote just recently!) That one was just a list of all events. This is an investigation into the similarity of some events.

Comment: If there is such a thing, I'd appreciate a link to any documentation (not source code) that explains the difference between these events. Otherwise, I'd appreciate some guidance on when to use each one.

Comment: Why would you ever use events? What for? Mongoose provides you methods (e.g. Mongoose.disconnect(), Connection.close()) to use).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are all the mongoose events and where are they documented?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54485936/what-are-all-the-mongoose-events-and-where-are-they-documented)

Comment: @mat.mik So I know whether the driver reconnected, disconnected, etc. Event handlers print stuff to my logs. Why would you *not* use events?

Comment: Still seems like internal things between mongoose and node-mongodb-native.